# model which belongs to User, unable to access user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an app in which week objects may be approved or rejected, this is done in the week controller. My week model belongs_to user. Here is a short example of what I'm doing in the week controller:

The first block is provided for some context:

```
def approve
@user = current_user
if params[:commit] == "Approve selected weeks"
  Week.where(id: params[:weeks_ids]).update_all(approved?: true)
  flash[:success] = "Selected weeks were approved!"
  #Send an email noting it was approved
  @user.send_approved(current_user)
```

Below is the rejection half:

```
elsif params[:commit] == "Reject selected weeks"
  user_week = Week.where(id: params[:weeks_ids])
  user_week.update_all(approved?: false)
```

Above, the weeks are updated perfectly. Below, I try to retrieve a user from the selected week so that I can send an email to that user.

```
  #get the user associated with the rejected week, send them an email.
  user_email = User.find(id: user_week.user_id)
  UserMailer.send_rejection(user_email).deliver

  flash[:info] = "Selected weeks were Rejected."
  end
  redirect_to weeks_path
end
```

When I try to reject a week however, I receive the following error:

```
undefined method `user_id' for <Week::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fdcac43e730>
```

Is this due to an unspecified User object?

Comment: Note-I'm adding on to pre-existing code here and have very little knowledge of MVC or rails syntax. I've looked around stack overflow all day and somehow haven't found anything that looks the same, but I could certainly be mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Week::ActiveRecord_Relation` is a *set* of records, not just a single one... it's like calling `user_id` on an array, which won't quite work the way you want.

What you want is to call `user_id` on a single instance of `Week` 
To do that you can either:

a) fetch out a single week (probably not what you want)

b) run `each` on the Active Relation eg:

```
user_weeks.each do |user_week|
  #get the user associated with the rejected week, send them an email.
  user_email = User.find(user_week.user_id)
  UserMailer.send_rejection(user_email).deliver
end
```

c) fetch the set of user_emails by converting the user_weeks to user_ids (but then iterate over the emails) eg:

```
# get the user associated with the rejected week, send them an email.
users = User.find(user_weeks.pluck(:user_id))
users.each do |user|
  UserMailer.send_rejection(user).deliver
end
```

d) assume that it's always for the same user anyway and just use the first week eg:

```
  #get the user associated with the rejected week, send them an email.
  user_email = User.find(user_week.first.user_id)
  UserMailer.send_rejection(user_email).deliver
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I now have the following error: "Couldn't find User with 'id'={:id=>[7]}" when selecting a week associated with the seventh user. Is the answer for this question too verbose for the comments?

Comment: oh yes... `find` doesn't require that you use `id` and I just copied your code. i'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Now it seems I have a problem with my mailer.."undefined method `send_rejection' for UserMailer:Class" but that's certainly enough for a new question.

Answer (score 1):

`user_week` appears to be a collection of weeks, not a single week.

What you are probably looking for is to send multiple rejection emails. You can loop over all weeks in `user_weeks` and send multiple emails by doing:

```
  elsif params[:commit] == "Reject selected weeks"
    user_weeks = Week.where(id: params[:weeks_ids])
    user_weeks.update_all(approved?: false)     
    user_weeks.each do |w|
      user_email = User.find(id: w.user_id)
      UserMailer.send_rejection(user_email).deliver
    end
    flash[:info] = "Selected weeks were Rejected."
  end
  redirect_to weeks_path
end
```